# Sometimes timestamp is not output at pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

My node module uses the --log-date-format option to pm2 to include timestamp when outputting console.log. By the way The timestamp may sometimes be missing in the node module's log.

For example,

```
2018-03-01 17:04:02 hello 1
2018-03-01 17:04:02 hello 2
hello 3
2018-03-01 17:04:03 hello 4
```

How can I solve this problem? Is this because pm2 is still immature?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is that issue?

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/183

But, that not complite solve, but closed now. In comments pm2 sometimes problem with `--log-date-format`

Comment: It seems to be different from the issue. The problem seems to occur when `console.log` is output consecutively. Since pm2 is a node anyway, it is assumed that there is a hole in event handling method.